# in Bootstrap4- I need to submit Modal Form using php

Tags: php, html, post, model

I am building this [website](http://www.snackhousekg.com/eng/) for a takeaway restaurant and the client requested 2 models one for career (receiving the resumes ) and the other for subscription to email updates.

How can I let the Form of the MODEL send the data to a Php page for GET_POST ?

The reason I am asking this is I need to record all the Model data to a database of the server not only send an email with the data.

First Model @join us

```html
<div class="modal" id="JoinModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Subscribe for our updates</h5>
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="addmail.php" method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="fname" placeholder="Name" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-success" value="Submit">Join</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The other model for receiving the resumes

```html
<!-- Career MODAL -->
<div class="modal" id="CareerModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Join our Team</h5>
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Name</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="familyname">Family Name</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Family Name" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="cv">Attach your CV</label>
            <input type='file' name='cv' id='cv' class='form-control' ><br>
          <input type='button' class='btn btn-info' value='Upload' id='upload'>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">Apply</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What you're asking for is too broad and unclear. I think that now would be a good time for you to go over the help area if you haven't already https://stackoverflow.com/help and the related links inside it. Read through that and you'll see how things work here on Stack Overflow. It will give you a good idea as to how to formulate a good question, to see what can and should not be asked, as well as what is expected from you. This was made and put into place in order to help (you) have a better and positive experience here on Stack Overflow, which is what everybody wants and aims for.

Comment: It is similar to other forms. Just add the action and in that page and method and on the next page use $_POST['name of the input'] and $_GET['name of input'] and add the name attributes to every input for eg. use this https://www.formget.com/insert-data-in-database-using-php/

Answer (score 0):

you can use ajax that will help you to perform parallel operation
e.g : inserting to database and sending mail

hope, it works for you